# AngularJS: Cloning element containing ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a directive with Angular 1.6 which creates a fixed header for a table. I am trying to achieve this by clone the table header and fixing this. This all works fine in most of my tables. I am using scope: false to keep parent scope, as some header elements references e.g. sorting functions. This also works. My problem is with one table I have which creates columns based on an array, because I want to be able to change columns. The columns are added with ng-repeat. When I clone this header, the ng-repeat is not cloned.

What can I do to clone an element containing an ng-repeat?

HTML of table:

```
<table class="proloen-table no-last-border" table-fix-header>
  <thead class="light-blue-background">
    <tr>
      <th>{{vm.testString}}</th>
      <th ng-repeat="head in vm.tableHeaders">
        <span>{{ head.label | translate }}</span>
        <sorting sortkey="head.sort" color="'white'" filter="vm.state.sorting"></sorting>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ...
</table>
```

Controller (with controllerAs: 'vm') has (among other things):

```
vm.testString = 'Test';
vm.tableHeaders = [{label: 'Column1', sort: 'prop1'}, {label: 'Column2', sort: 'prop2'}];
```

The directive is as follows:

```
.directive('tableFixHeader', function ($window, $compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: false,
  link: function (scope, element) {
    var clone;

    function init() {
      element.wrap('<div class="fix-table-container"></div>');
      clone = element.clone(true);
      clone.find('tbody').remove().end().addClass('table-header-fixed');
      clone.removeAttr('table-fix-header');
      $compile(clone)(scope);
      element.before(clone);
      resizeFixed();
    }
    function resizeFixed() {        
      clone.find('th').each(function (index) {
        $(this).css('width', element.find('th').eq(index).outerWidth() + 'px');
      });
    }
    function scrollFixed() {
      var offset = $($window).scrollTop(),
        tableOffsetTop = element.offset().top,
        tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + element.height() - element.find('thead').height();
      if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom){
        clone.hide();
      }
      else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && clone.is(':hidden')) {
        clone.show();
      }
    }

    $window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFixed);
    $window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFixed);

    scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFixed);
      $window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeFixed);
    });

    init();
  }
};
});
```

The directive works fine for tables columns are fixed and the above example clones the first "hardcoded" column just fine, along the variable from controller. The problem arises when cloning the ng-repeat. I just can't seem to figure out how to clone the ng-repeat, so that it to will work and update when I update the list of columns.

Comment: Use timeout (to wait ng-repeat loaded first). **$timeout(function(){
      init();
});**

Answer (score 0):

You could try to send event with `$scope.$emit` when `ng-repeat` finished rendering. Or create own event emitter and connect your directives;

```
 app.directive('onFinishRepeat', function(){

     return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope) {

           if($scope.$last == true) {
               $scope.$emit('ng-repeat', 'finish');
           } 

        }

     }

 })

app.directive('tableFixHeader', function ($window, $compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: false,
  link: function (scope, element) {
    var clone;

    function init() {
      element.wrap('<div class="fix-table-container"></div>');
      clone = element.clone(true);
      clone.find('tbody').remove().end().addClass('table-header-fixed');
      clone.removeAttr('table-fix-header');
      $compile(clone)(scope);
      element.before(clone);
      resizeFixed();
    }
    function resizeFixed() {        
      clone.find('th').each(function (index) {
        $(this).css('width', element.find('th').eq(index).outerWidth() + 'px');
      });
    }
    function scrollFixed() {
      var offset = $($window).scrollTop(),
        tableOffsetTop = element.offset().top,
        tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + element.height() - element.find('thead').height();
      if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom){
        clone.hide();
      }
      else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && clone.is(':hidden')) {
        clone.show();
      }
    }

    $window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFixed);
    $window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFixed);

    scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFixed);
      $window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeFixed);
    });

    $scope.on('ng-repeat', function(event, data){

        if(data == 'finish') {

           init();

        }

    }) 
  }
};
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="proloen-table no-last-border" table-fix-header>
<thead class="light-blue-background">
<tr>
  <th>{{vm.testString}}</th>
  <th ng-repeat="head in vm.tableHeaders" on-finish-repeat>
    <span>{{ head.label | translate }}</span>
    <sorting sortkey="head.sort" color="'white'" filter="vm.state.sorting"></sorting>
  </th>
</tr>
</thead>
 ...
</table>
```